# Fill shapefile with data when the attribute tables do not have the same number of rows

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table

I have an "empty" polygon shapefile. It only has one row in its attribute table.

I have one attribute table called "owf" I would like to join to the polygon. Unfortunately, when I join the two tables, only one row from the "owf" table will join to the polygon.

What am I doing wrong that is keeping me from adding the whole table to the polygon?

I am using ArcMap 10.3

[image: polygon attribute table]

[image: owf attribute table]

Comment: Join merges across, not down.  This is a "one-to-many" relationship, which can be handled in several different ways.  The [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/about-joining-and-relating-tables.htm) has details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually join attribute has a one-to-one or a many-to-one relationship as shown in the documentation in Vince comment, however there is other solutions presented [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/36viu1/does_anyone_know_how_to_make_a_one_to_many_join/) you can try it, which is as follows:

1. Open ArcToolbox.
2. Go to "Data Management Tools".
3. Click on "Layers and Table Views".
4. Double click "Make Query Table".
5. Select the correct "Input Tables" you would like to join.
6. I always click on "Select All" for the "Fields".
7. Next to the "Expression" box, click the SQL button.
8. Double click the field from Table1 that is suppose to connect to
   Table2.
9. Click the "=" button.
10. Double click the field from Table2 that will connect to Table1.
11. It should look like "Table1.joinfield" = "Table2.joinfield"
12. Click Okay.
13. For some reason, you have to remove the quotes from the Expression
     field so that it reads Table1.joinfield = Table2.joinfield.
14. I usually just leave the "Key Fields" alone.
15. Now click Okay and you should have a resulting table that is a one
     to many join.

Comment: Thanks and walking me through the steps, ahmadhand. This solved it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save you polygon in FGDB if its not there
2. Join polygon (right click join) to table
3. Right click on it in table of content and export to file geodatabase
   feature class

NOTE: you'll get N identical polygons with different info attached to them.